# is it possible to configure Ant to compile only the changed classes

Tags: java, ant

1. Is there any way to configure ANT to compile only the changed modules?

   my suggestion is to specify the change module in a build property and execute based on property file content. For example if compile with below target.

   ```
   <target name="compile-source" depends="init" description="compile the source ">
   <javac destdir="${target.classes.dir}" debug="true">            
      <src path="${source.java.dir}/module1"/>
      <src path="${source.java.dir}/module2"/>                 
       <classpath refid="libs"/>
   </javac>
   </target>
   ```
2. Is there a way to evaluate time taken for each target ?

Answer (score 2):

By default javac only compile modified files it check the timestamp of .class file and check it it older than .java file.

Answer (score 2):

From the Ant documentation for the javac task:

> Compiles a Java source tree.
>
> The source and destination directory will be recursively scanned for
>   Java source files to compile. Only Java files that have no
>   corresponding .class file or where the class file is older than the
>   .java file will be compiled.

http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html

Answer (score 0):

So if you are not deleting the classes directory in any dependent task say 'clean'
the javac task inherently compiles only the changed java files. It is an out of the box feature that javac task provides.